# What is the best way to redirect http request

Tags: linux, oracle, rest, web-services, plsql

I have Oracle database sever where is no conection to internet.
I have also linux server with i can connect to internet. From database i would like to send request (GET and POST) by utl_http package to linux server and linux server will transfer this request to websiste and return the answer. I don't want to install apache, tomcat or other havy serwers. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You can install a light wight http proxy like squid [debian like](https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-in-ubuntu/) [redhad like](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-squid-proxy-on-centos-7/) on your public node (or configure proxy mod for apache httpd), and then configure [proxy for utl_http](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#i1011581)

Comment: To echo what @VictorGubin said, you are trying to use your Linux box as an HTTP proxy for your database server.  There are many ways to do this, but they are all going to require installing some kind of proxy software, be it Apache (which is pretty straight forward and part of any Linux Distro), squid or some other proxy software solution.  If there _were_ a way to bounce an HTTP proxy off your linux box without any such software being installed and configured, I would suggest you have a CRITICAL security breach on your hands.

Comment: If solution that @VictorGubin said i critical for security, what others solution will you reccomend?

Comment: Your only real choice is to configure a proxy server on the linux box and configure utl_http to use it.  There may be some out there that you can run from the command line so you don't have to install, but you would need access to the box to run it and any Linux admin worth their salt should revoke your access if this is to be used in a production environment.

Comment: `critical for security` then you'd better find another solution, i.e. not send anything from the database directly, but use some middleware software between the database and external system. I.e. some simple java spring boot app or : node.js, python/django, ruby on rails etc.